# How to continue Zapier zap when no record found in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, zapier

I'm using Zapier to look for contacts and leads in Salesforce. If a person is not listed as a contact AND not listed as a lead, then I want to create a lead.

The test zap stops when the person is not found in contacts. I want take action if no record is found (search result is empty). Is there any way to do this with Zapier steps?

Comment: Zapier requires some data to proceed. If the person is not a contact nor a lead, what are they exactly (in Salesforce)? Maybe that's the type of data you should trigger on (if possible).

Comment: I want to determine that the person is not in the system before I try to add them. I want to make sure they are not a contact before I try to create a new lead in Salesforce. But if the zap cannot proceed to the javascript code of the next step, then I may have to write PHP code and not use Zapier for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that has worked for us.

**Zap #1 - Creates a Lead if no Contact record is found**

1. Search for SF Contact
2. If none found, create new Contact but populate the Contact record with "dummy/placeholder data".  (LastName="Placeholder" FirstName="Zapier")
3. Then continue onto the next step and Create a Lead with the data from your form (or whatever triggering input you need)

**Zap #2 - Updates a Contact Record if Found**

1. Search for Contact
2. If Found, Update Contact Record
3. Filter that if None Found then Zap ends

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger has to specifically look for people that are *not* contacts or leads, and return that, so subsequent actions can work with it. If your trigger just returns all people (regardless if they are contacts or leads), then you'll either need a Zapier filter or "search" step to narrow down which data continues onto the "action" step of the zap.

Comment: Salesforce search actions will return the most recently created record that meets the search criteria, even if there are multiple records that match.[link](https://zapier.com/help/salesforce/#supported-searches). So I can't get a list then filter it.